# Generic interfaces and operator overloading - how to set procedure from generic interface block to be private in module?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

My IDE is: Code::Blocks 20.03 ( MinGW 9.2.0 )

This is my code:

```
module mod_kompleks

  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only : rp => c_double

  implicit none

  type, public :: kom_bro

    real(rp), private :: rea
    real(rp), private :: img

    contains

      procedure, pass(kdt), private :: kom_bro_ini
      procedure, pass(kdt),  public :: uzm_rea => uzm_pod_rea
      procedure, pass(kdt),  public :: uzm_img => uzm_pod_img
      procedure, pass(kdt), private :: kom_bro_sab

      generic, public :: operator(+) => kom_bro_sab

  end type kom_bro

  interface kom_bro

    module procedure kom_bro_kon

  end interface kom_bro

  private :: kom_bro_kon

contains

  function kom_bro_kon( bro_rea, bro_img ) result( bro )

    real(rp), intent(in) :: bro_rea
    real(rp), intent(in) :: bro_img
    type(kom_bro)        :: bro

    call bro%kom_bro_ini(bro_rea, bro_img)

  end function kom_bro_kon

  subroutine kom_bro_ini(kdt, dio_rea, dio_img)

    class(kom_bro), intent(out) :: kdt
     real(rp),      intent(in)  :: dio_rea
     real(rp),      intent(in)  :: dio_img

     kdt%rea = dio_rea
     kdt%img = dio_img

  end subroutine kom_bro_ini

  function uzm_pod_rea( kdt ) result( rez )

    class(kom_bro), intent(in) :: kdt
     real(rp)                  :: rez

     rez = kdt%rea

  end function uzm_pod_rea

  function uzm_pod_img( kdt ) result( rez )

    class(kom_bro), intent(in) :: kdt
     real(rp)                  :: rez

     rez = kdt%img

  end function uzm_pod_img

  function kom_bro_sab( kdt, bro ) result( rez )

    class(kom_bro), intent(in) :: kdt
    class(kom_bro), intent(in) :: bro
     type(kom_bro)             :: rez

     rez%rea = kdt%rea + bro%rea
     rez%img = kdt%img + bro%img

  end function kom_bro_sab

end module mod_kompleks

program kompleksni_broj

  use, non_intrinsic :: mod_kompleks

  implicit none

  type(kom_bro) :: broj_01, broj_02, broj_03

  broj_01 = kom_bro(1.1_rp,2.2_rp)

  print '(1x,f4.2,1x,"j",1xf4.2)', broj_01%uzm_rea(), broj_01%uzm_img()

  broj_02 = kom_bro(3.3_rp,4.4_rp)

  print '(1x,f4.2,1x,"j",1xf4.2)', broj_02%uzm_rea(), broj_02%uzm_img()

  broj_03 = broj_01 + broj_02

  print '(1x,f4.2,1x,"j",1xf4.2)', broj_03%uzm_rea(), broj_03%uzm_img()

end program kompleksni_broj
```

My intention is to disable access to the `kom_bro_sab` procedure outside the `mod_kompleks` module. In case I want to construct a complex number with values for the real and imaginary part in the main program, after typing the word kom I get the opportunity to choose the procedure `kon_bro`, which of course I wanted, but next to that function I am offered the opportunity to choose the procedure `kom_bro_sab`. How can I prevent this (I want only the procedure `kom_bro_sab` and the operator `+` to be visible)?
I will add screenshot of what i got even the type - bound procedure was private:
[image: kom_bro_sab]

Comment: I struggle to understand this question (why don't you declare the procedure `private`), so could you please look at whether you need all those other bits you have in the code example?

Comment: "My intention is to disable access to the kom_bro_sab procedure" and "I want only the procedure kom_bro_sab and the operator + to be visible" seem to contradict.

Comment: @francescalus As far as I understand it OP wants to access `kom_bro_sab` only via the *type-bound* generic name `generic, public :: operator(+) => kom_bro_sab` and *not* as a standard function.

Comment: @francescalus The procedure vas declared: `procedure, pass(kdt), private :: kom_bro_sab`. But. again that procedure is visible in main program.

Comment: @jack Only constructor procedure `kom_bro` and operator I want to use in main program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short**

The `kom_bro_sab` function has (default) access property `public` which is why you can access `kom_bro_sab` in your main program.

**Explanation**

The function `kom_bro_sab` is exported as any other function would be because its access property is `public`.
This is because by default the access property is `public` and was not changed here.

Dont be confused by the line `procedure, pass(kdt), private :: kom_bro_sab`.
Here a *type-bound* procedure `kom_bro_sab` is defined and which has access property `private`.
Thus, you can only call this property from other type-bound procedures.
You should differentiate between the type-bound procedure and the function itself.

**Solutions**

There are two ways to handle it.

1. Changing the default access property to `private` and only explicitly defining the `public` entities. This also makes it easier when quickly looking through modules to see which entities are actually exported.

```
module mod_kompleks
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only : rp => c_double
  implicit none
  private
  public kom_bro
  
  type kom_bro
...
end module
```

2. You could keep at what you were doing by explicitly defining `public` and `private` properties. Then you just need to add one line (see the line containing `ADDED`).

```
module mod_kompleks
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only : rp => c_double
  implicit none
  type, public :: kom_bro
...
  end interface kom_bro
  private kom_bro_kon
  private kom_bro_sab     ! <- ADDED
...
end module
```

---

I shortened your code and hope that it is still understandable.

Comment: Why is it necessary to add this line if I have already stated explicitly above: `procedure, pass(kdt), private :: kom_bro_sab`

Comment: After the explanation, I think about whether it is necessary to write the stated line at all.

Answer (score 1):

For the overloaded `operator(+)` to work in

```
broj_03 = broj_01 + broj_02
```

we have three different aspects to consider:

- the module procedure `kom_bro_sab`
- the specific type-bound procedure with binding name `kom_bro_sab`
- the generic type-bound interface `operator(+)`

Each of these has its own accessibility, and is a distinct thing.

Look at the statement we have.  In

```
broj_03 = broj_01 + broj_02
```

we can see that when we consider the generic `operator(+)` we have left-hand side `class(kom_bro)` and right-hand side `class(kom_bro)`: we have a match to the specific type-bound procedure `kom_bro_sab`. We can make this assessment outside the module because this generic interface is *public*. This resolution does not need the specific type-bound procedure to be public.

Assuming the binding name is accessible, this previous statement can be written as a reference to a specific type-bound procedure looking like

```
broj_03 = broj_01%kom_bro_sab(broj_02)
```

which finally, assuming the module procedure is accessible, looks like

```
broj_03 = kom_bro_sab(broj_01, broj_02)
```

We can independently control access of each of these things.

In the code of the question you have the specific binding `kom_bro_sab` private, but the module procedure `kom_bro_sab` is public because the default accessibility of the module is public.

[jack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65603601/3157076) shows how you can make the default accessibility private, or have default accessibility public but make the module procedure private.  You have already specified your desired access to the specific and generic bindings.

Comment: After the explanation, things became clearer to me, but I still don't understand why this procedure is visible outside the module, even though I declared it like this: `procedure, pass(kdt), private :: kom_bro_sab`. That's why I made a small change to the question, I just added a picture of what is offered as an option when I want to call a constructor of a complex number. Can you explain further to me?

Comment: `procedure, pass(kdt), private :: kom_bro_sab` declares the _type-bound_ procedure `kom_bro_sab` which is a different thing from the module procedure `kom_bro_sab`. You will also need to make that module procedure private (`private kom_bro_sab`). It may help you see this difference if you rename the module procedure to something else, like `function mp_kom_bro_sab (..)` coupled with `procedure, pass(kdt), private :: kom_bro_sab => mp_kom_bro_sab`. They currently have the same name, but they are different things.

Comment: Just to conclude, therefore, operator-related procedures should not be declared after contains commands within a user-defined type, but should be defined as module procedures with the private attribute? In case I declare them as I did, it would be logical that I can use the operator in the main program, but also that function to get the same effect on objects?

Comment: You are better having the operator generics within the derived type (using a type-bound procedure specific) in many/most cases. That way the operator is always accessible whenever the derived type is.  If using the module procedure and generic on that, then you wouldn't be able to have `use mod_kompleks, only : kom_bro` (which you can with type-bound generic) but instead the more cumbersome `use mod_kompleks, only : kom_bro, operator(+)`.

Comment: So, I can't use the operator without declaring its procedure(`procedure, private :: kom_bro_sab`) below the contains command in a user-defined type, because in that case the compiler will report this error to me: `Error: Undefined specific binding 'kom_bro_sab' as target of GENERIC '+'`  
After that, I can control the right of access as explained in all the previous answers.

Comment: Correct: to have a generic type-bound interface (within the "contains") you must have a specific type-bound procedure (again, after contains). You can, however, have the operator generic in the module (outside the derived type definition) but I prefer the approach you have in the question.